# Can I setup a single connection pool for multiple processes for MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I understand the most common case is to maintain a per-process connection pool, and the connections in this pool are shared among multiple threads. However, this solution has some problems when there're too many instances of processes running.

Hence, we want to improve this by maintaining a single connection spool, and share the connections across processes. However, I'm not sure if this is feasible, since I've no idea whether the native MySQL connection handle (MYSQL structure) can be shared across processes. Or some additional design effort is required?

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQL Relay for this: http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/

But I do wonder why you'd want to? Creating new connections in MySQL is a very lightweight process, 1 connection per process (or even multiple) shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Sorry, seems I didn't put things clearly. Not 1 connection per process, but 1 connection pool per process. Each pool has several connections, say 5. And in our env, we've 16 processes, which means there could be 80 connections at the most.

Comment: I did understand, but personally I wouldn't recommend sharing MySQL connections between multiple processes which is why I recommended SQL Relay, which does this nicely for you. You might be able to get it working bugfree, but I don't see why you would need to bother :)